# Where are all the guides and samples on how to configure DRM in the Google Cloud Transcoder API?

Tags: encryption, drm, google-cloud-transcoder

I want to configure DRM using Google Transcoder API, but I can't find related samples or guides.
Has the DRM setting function deprecated?
Although it is a beta version, there was also a [release note](https://cloud.google.com/transcoder/docs/release-notes#November_16_2020) that the DRM function was added.
Or has this function been transferred to another API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a note in the August 2021 release around DRM:

> Encryption support (and its associated documentation) is temporarily unavailable.

(https://cloud.google.com/transcoder/docs/release-notes#August_31_2021)

There is no note following that suggesting that it has been added back in - you are correct that there was previously online documentation for DRM but those links are no longer live from what I have seen.